# Laravel 5.2 - Redis - Socket.io publish doesn't work

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, laravel-5

I've a laravel installation on a windows 10 machine.
I've written this simple route

```
Route::get('/event', function(){
    $data = array("key"=>"val");
    Redis::publish('test-channel', json_encode($data));
});
```

then i've this node server.js

```
var server = require('http').Server();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var Redis = require('ioredis');
redis = new Redis();
redis.subscribe('test-channel');

redis.on('message', function(channel, message){
  console.log("message retriving..");
});

server.listen(6001, function(){
  console.log('listening on 6001');
});
```

I've an Ubuntu installation on a virtual machine on which i've installed Redis.

My laravel .env file is

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
REDIS_HOST=192.168.1.14 #ubuntu ip
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

The problem is that when the route '/event' is executed (and the node server is listening) .. I don't receive any message on the 'test-channel'

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel add prefix before channel name. You can check the prefix in **config/database.php** then find `redis => options => prefix`. By default, the prefix is `laravel_database_` so you need to subscribe `laravel_database_test-channel` instead of `test-channel`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
redis = new Redis();
```

to:

```
redis = new Redis('6379', 'Redis');
```